# receiving a linux signal and interating with threads

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, signals

hello to you all :)
i have a program that have a n number of threads(could be a lot) and they do a pretty extensive job. My problem is that sometimes some people turn off or reboot the server(the program runs all day  in the company servers) i know that there is a way to make a handler for the linux signals i want to know what  i should do to interact with all threads making them to use run a function and then stop working. There is a way to do that?

sorry the bad english :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way of handling this is not requiring any shutdown actions at all.

For example, your signal handler for (e.g.) SIGTERM or SIGQUIT can just call _exit and quit the process with no clean-up.

Under Linux (with non-ancient threads) when one thread calls _exit (or exit if you really want) other threads get stopped too - whatever they were in the middle of doing.

This would be good as it implements a crash-only design.

Crash-only design for a server is based on the principle that the machine may crash at any point, so you need to be able to recover from such a failure anyway, so just make it the normal way of quitting. No extra code should be required as your server should be robust enough anyway.

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing you can do is set a global variable from your signal handler, and have your threads check its value periodically.

Comment: In general, signal handlers should only call syscalls documented as "async-safe" and library functions documented as "reentrant".  Obviously adding threading to the program adds another layer of restrictions, and so I can understand the temptation to just give up and say "do nothing in a signal handler except set a variable", but I feel it's a bit too strong of a statement.

Comment: It's less of "you can't do stuff from a signal handler" and more of "Python intentionally has no API for forcefully terminating a thread".

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, signal handlers can get messy (due to the restrictions, particularly in multi-threaded programs), so it's better to chose another option:

- have a dedicated thread for handling signals via [sigwaitinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigwaitinfo) - the bad news, though, is that python doesn't appear to support that out of the box.
- use the Linux-specific [signalfd](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd) to handle signals (either in a separate thread or integrated into some event loop) - at least there is a [python-signalfd](https://launchpad.net/python-signalfd) module you can use.

As there is no need to install signal handlers here, there is no restriction on what you can do when you are notified of a signal and it should be easy to shut down the others threads in your program cleanly.